# MySQL sometimes decrease field value

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, innodb

I have the field named `hits` in my table which records user interaction with objects on my website. For example: if user views object preview field `hits` would be updated and increased by 1, if user enters object's page it would be increased by 3 and etc.

Everything works like a charm on my local development server. But on production server (online > 50) sometimes field `hits` increases by right value and then within several seconds it could be decreased by some random small value (1,2). This bug doesn't always occur. I think the solution can be related with MyISAM engine I'm currently using for this table.

Below is a code implementing table update query (codeigniter)

```
    $this->db->set('hits', 'hits+' . (int) $count, FALSE);
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('gallery');
```

So I have 2 questions:

- How to fix this bug?
- How can I perform multiple queries to my table to duplicate this situation on my local development server?

Comment: Pretty sure, problem not here

Comment: possible overlapping 'transactions' in myIsam? i.e. myIsam does not do transactions. You need sequential updates but are getting nested ones. So, you have two users read the same current value. First user updates and saves it. second user updates and saves it. You lose the first user update. It will appear to go up if your read after the first user update then down after the second user update. You need to apply locking around your read and update.

Comment: Looks like you would have to [Lock the table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/internal-locking.html) But that might well produce a new set of issues as multiple updates get queued

Comment: MyIsam doesn't really support transactions, use InnoDB instead and you should be covered against these kind of issues.

Comment: That Update should be atomic even in MyISAM.  What else is going on around the Update?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for responses. Anyway I got useful information from your answers. The problem was at the crontask. I had a function running every minute every third month. It cutted these hits. I fixed that crontask and everything works now. 
Check your crontask twice. Thanks you all for your help.